# UWP Error 'directxdatabasehelper.cpp 80070005 Access is denied' when compiling for x64 Release mode with .NET Native on

Tags: uwp, release, .net-native

I have a UWP app that works perfect when in x64 Debug mode but fails when in x64 release mode with .NET Native on (works in release with .Net Native off). When it fails, I received the following error before any code is run in my app:

> onecore\windows\directx\database\helperlibrary\lib\directxdatabasehelper.cpp(527)\directxdatabasehelper.dll!00007FFDA305836B: (caller: 00007FFDA305409D) ReturnHr(1) tid(8da0) 80070005 Access is denied.

I don't know for sure, but I think this may be related to some audio processing I am trying to do with the AudioGraph, but I really don't know.  I do know that the audio processing functions, specifically:

```
CreateAudioGraphResult = Await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(Settings)
```

Fails hard when using .NET Native.

Has anyone else seen this before? Google has been no help.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is this exception thrown from that line of code -`Await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(Settings)`?

Comment: No, the exception above is thrown before any code user is run (i.e., before app.xaml.vb, in my case).  The line of code I noted may be a red herring.  I mentioned it because I expect that the audiograph is using DirectX and I am receiving many errors in calls to the audiograph functions, too, but after more review, I am also finding that .NET Native is calling my subroutines in a different order than they are called without, so some code seems to be being called before other parts are initialized.  I really have no idea if the issues are actually related.

Comment: Note - after more review, I was able to fix the crashing problem. I was indeed related to .NET Native calling methods in a different order. This seem to be related to async methods finishing faster under .NET native than under general debug.  So, in the end, the only issue I am trying to figure out here is the directxdatabasehelper Access is denied error.  The app does run, but I really don't like seeing errors like this.

Comment: I've talked this with the team. This requires help from the .NET Native team, if the email contact is not available, you might need to open a paid support ticket for this. Please go to https://support.serviceshub.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness/create. Select **Developer Tools -> Windows UWP Development -> Windows 10 Universal App Dev -> Runtime Platform-> .NET Native** in the support page and you could contact the team.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, thank you very much.  Since I was able to get the app compiled with .NET Native and running, even with the above errors, I ran it through the Windows App Cert Kit.  It fails the test with a crash of the default splash screen I have not seen before, but only on the compiled for publish and installed version.  Clearly, I need to get this resolved, so I will contact MS as you noted.